# Profile was replaced when I signed on to my Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, sync, user-profiles, microsoft-account

I am trying to set up my mom's computer. It is running Win 10 upgraded from Win 7. I created a standard profile for her and named it Joxxxxxxx. I was went to Windows Store to get some programs/apps for her. It made me sign into Windows Store by using my microsoft account and password. I down loaded what I wanted and then powered off the computer.

When I went to log in with a profile Joxxxxxxxx was **gone** and it was replaced with one of the profiles from my computer. It required me to give it the password (same as Microsoft Account. When I opened the "new" profile I find MY desktop from my computer. What has happened? Both of the computers are using the same WiFi right now.

I deleted the NEW profile and created another Joxxxxxxxx profile from scratch. I need to set this one up and need to use a super simple desktop with only the apps and programs she can use, Facebook, solitaire, and a few others.

The computers are not SYNCed.

Is there a fix out there for this? I have worked all day on it and am making no headway.

I have searched and found a few post but they were all about Win 8 and not Win 10.